# XML: Should I use namespaces or more complex tag names

Tags: xml, namespaces, tags

I have a question regarding namespaces in a XML file.
For example, imagine that we have a XML that will contain 2 differnt types of elements (offers and tickets, let's say), and both of them have the same attributes (id, descripcion, price).

Which is the best option to describe them? using "namespaces" or "unique identifiers"?

```
...

<root>

<kits xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string">
    <kit>
        <kit_id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></kit_id>
        <kit_description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></kit_description>
        <kit_price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></kit_price>
    </kit>
    <kit>
        <kit_id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></kit_id>
        <kit_description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></kit_description>
        <kit_price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></kit_price>
    </kit>
</kits> 

<tickets xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string">
    <ticket>
        <ticket_id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></ticket_id>
        <ticket_description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></ticket_description>
        <ticket_price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></ticket_price>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <ticket_id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></ticket_id>
        <ticket_description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></ticket_description>
        <ticket_price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></ticket_price>
    </ticket>
</tickets>  

</root>
```

or

```
...

<root xmlns:kit="http://www.questionstack.test/kit" xmlns:tic="http://www.questionstack.test/ticket">

<kits xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string">
    <kit>
        <kit:id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></kit:id>
        <kit:description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></kit:description>
        <kit:price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></kit:price>
    </kit>
    <kit>
        <kit:id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></kit:id>
        <kit:description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></kit:description>
        <kit:price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></kit:price>
    </kit>
</kits> 

<tickets xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string">
    <ticket>
        <tic:id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></tic:id>
        <tic:description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></tic:description>
        <tic:price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></tic:price>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <tic:id xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:long"></tic:id>
        <tic:description xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:string"></tic:description>
        <tic:price xmlns="" xsi:type="xsd:double"></tic:price>
    </ticket>
</tickets>  

</root>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Different namespaces are only required if plan on using more than one schema.    if you have a very large schema, you may want to split the schema into multiple files and then you will need more than one namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jdweng